# dvi to hdmi isn't working correctly

Tags: fedora, hdmi, nvidia-graphics-card, dvi

I have a DVI to HDMI converter for my television.  I used to use DVI to VGA and it worked correctly.  I switched, and now the television won't display my screen properly.  The info:

- nvidia with gforce 9600
- fedora 16 (soon to be 17)
- RCA LED 24" television

what's going on is that the television will stretch the screen outside of the limits of the screen, so I don't see about 1-1.5 inches of the outer edges.  When I go into the settings for the resolution, it tells me that the screen is 19" television, which it isn't.  Plus, it's on the highest resolution.  I tried to change to a lower res, but the screen is still stretched.  Taking away the nvidia nouvaeu drivers does nothing but crash my xorg.  And help on this?

Comment: Why did you switch from a VGA connection to HDMI?  What is the actual (aka *native*) resolution of the RCA display?  Are there any display modes on the RCA TV for one-to-one pixel mapping (aka "just fit" mode)?  BTW what you are seeing is called **overscan** (of the image).

Comment: The weird part is that it work until I do a software update on the system.  I reinstalled my OS a couple of times while trying to fix this problem.  I switched out to HDMI for a better quality.